# Annoying choice of contact email/phone on CarPlay and iOS

Tags: ios, messages, facetime, car-integration

CarPlay uses what is configured on your iPhone.

Every time I try to use Siri on CarPlay to send a message or FaceTime someone, for example, `Siri send message to Susan` or `Siri facetime Susan`, then I have to hear the most obtuse and annoying question ever:

```
This person has two contacts, email blabla@bla.com and phone number "home", which one do you want to choose?
```

This is ridiculously annoying because I constantly message this person, ALWAYS using her email, and I know that her email and her phone number are both registered for messages and FaceTime. The most ridiculous part is that some contacts have multiple emails and phone numbers, but just one email and one phone number is presented.

Is there a way to edit the contact and mark an email or phone number as the preferred way to contact a person, so this step of making me choose for a method is eliminated?

Answer (score 0):

"Hey Siri… facetime Susan, home"
or whatever tag you have for them in Contacts.

Comment: ok, but imagine having to remember the tags for all phones and emails of every contact.

Comment: How many tags do you imagine you'd need? I use Home, Mobile, Work. That's about it for the people I need to use Siri to call or message.

Comment: I tested your idea now: "Siri, message Susan, email"... the answer "which one?... the same if it is a text message. So, sorry, your solution does not work. Yes, many of my contacts have multiple emails and phones

Comment: You need to be careful to enter the correct information into the various contacts fields  - experiment a bit - it works well when properly configured. I use it primarily with CarPlay as I can be on the road frequently and need to talk/text with a small number of colleagues as well as my significant other and not be concerned with choosing on the fly.

Comment: ↑ This. You need to organise your contacts first, not blame the 'secretary' for not being a mind reader.